# Presenting UIModalViews in landscape mode

Tags: cocoa-touch, rotation, modal-dialog, uimodalpresentationformsh

I'm trying to present some `UIModalFormSheets` in a my iPad application. It's working without any problems, except one thing:

When I have my iPad in landscape mode my modal form sheet is moving to the center of the screen and **then** rotates into the appropiate angle. All I want is to present the modal form sheet in the right angle according to the view mode (portrait or landscape), **before** it is displayed, so that the user doesn't see this rotation.

I have tried all the modes for `modalTransitionStyle` and `modalPresentationStyle`, but nothing seems to prevent the modal form sheet from rotating after it is displayed.

This is what I'm doing:

```
NewFavouriteSheet *newFavouriteSheet = [[NewFavouriteSheet alloc] 
                 initWithNibName:@"NewFavouriteSheet" bundle:nil];
newFavouriteSheet.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:newFavouriteSheet animated:NO];
```

Does anyone has a suggestion on how to show the modal view in a correct way?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure every view controller in your modal sheet responds appropriately to `shouldAutorotateToUserInterfaceOrientation:` for the landscape orientations.